# Devise undefined method `user_changed?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, nomethoderror

Rails 4.0.1 and devise 3.4.1

Receiving the following error, regardless whether it's sign_in or sign_up:

> **NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#create**
>
> undefined method `user_changed?' for #

Devise doesn't generate any controllers by default, and none were added; there isn't a registrations or sessions_controller.

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable

    devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :registerable

    mount_uploader :user, ImageUploader

end
```

Routes:

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :posts
  resources :projects
  resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]
  get 'welcome/index'
  root 'welcome#index'

  get '*path' => redirect('/')
end
```

Routes Table:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                   posts GET    /posts(.:format)               posts#index
                         POST   /posts(.:format)               posts#create
                new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)           posts#new
               edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)      posts#edit
                    post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#show
                         PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
                         PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
                         DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#destroy
                projects GET    /projects(.:format)            projects#index
                         POST   /projects(.:format)            projects#create
             new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)        projects#new
            edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format)   projects#edit
                 project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)        projects#show
                         PATCH  /projects/:id(.:format)        projects#update
                         PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)        projects#update
                         DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)        projects#destroy
                contacts POST   /contacts(.:format)            contacts#create
             new_contact GET    /contacts/new(.:format)        contacts#new
           welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)       welcome#index
                    root GET    /                              welcome#index
```

Code from app\views\devise\registrations\new.html.erb

```
  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: user_registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
```

And finally, code from devise\sessions\new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: user_session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
    </div>
```

Would greatly appreciate any help to regain the ability to sign back in or sign up.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The registrations and sessions controllers are built into devise.

I'm guessing this broke when you added u user photo?

Do you really have a field on your user table called `user` that holds your image?  If you so, you need to create a migration to create that name.

```
rails g migration rename_user_photo_field
```

Edit hte file

```
class RenameUserPhoto < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :users, :user, :photo
  end
end
```

Comment: trh, great question! I have the following under the **user** table in schema:  
`t.string   "image"`

latest migration:

`class AddImageToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration  
  def change  
    add_column :users, :image, :string  
  end  
end`

Comment: Does this mean I should follow your example with something like this?  
  
  `rename_column :users, :user, :image, :string`

Comment: If it's already a string you don't have to supply a data type, you're just renaming.  Any data changes you want to make to the column, then yes, you'd need to provide a complete definition :)

Comment: The migration didn't work...I tried adjusting  my User Model by changing `mount_uploader :user, ImageUploader` to **:users**. That didn't work either, so I commented out that line, and now I'm able to sign_in! I think the source of the problem is how carrierwave was installed. I want to upload images for Posts and Projects, so maybe :image shouldn't be under the users table in the db, or assigned to the User Model?